# Reset Tabs in Child Component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Consider two React components written in TypeScript where one is a child of the other. The child has tabs and maintains its own state as to which tab is currently selected:

```
export const ClientCategoryTabs: React.FunctionComponent<ClientCategoryTabsProps> = (props: ClientCategoryTabsProps) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState<ClientCategoryTabsState>({
        activeTab: "1"
    });
...}
```

There are other functions that toggle tabs on click as needed. The contents of the tabs may change, and that's handled in further descendants of this tabbed child component.

Meanwhile, there are events in the parent component that need to reset the active tab to the first.

While I know that providing new props can trigger a rerender, I can't figure out how to trigger a reset of the child state (well, just the tabs not the data inside the tabs) without leaking that state to the parent--in other words, maintaining the active tab state in the parent and then initializing child state with that value.

Any ideas on how to maintain that separation are appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like rethinking how the state is managed might be necessary. For example, what if the tab state was managed in the parent, and passed down to each tab as props.

Comment: Right. That's basically what I mentioned near the end. I was just curious if there was another way I was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a prop to the tab container that sets the active tab from outside:

```
<CategoryTabContainer activeTab={1} />

const CategoryTabContainer : React.FC<ClientCategoryTabsProps> = ({ activeTab = 1 }) => {
  const [activeTabValue, setActiveTabValue] = useState<number>(activeTab);

  // synchronize props with state
  useEffect(() => {
    if (activeTab !== activeTabValue) {
      setActiveTabValue(activeTab);
    }
  }, [activeTab]);

  // ...
}
```

Then, set the logic for reset state in parent component.

On the other hand, would you consider using `ContainerTabContainer` for rendering and using hooks to for setting the state?

```
const [activeTab, onTabClick, setActiveTab] = useTabs(tabData);

return (
  <>
    <button onClick={() => setActiveTab(0)}>Reset</button>
    <CategoryTabContainer activeTab={activeTab} onTabClick={onTabClick} />
  </>
);
```

I personally prefer this approach more as it is more direct and "Reacty" :)

Comment: The custom hook is cool, but for now I will probably go for the first option, which aligns with what I was thinking anyway. The only thing I kinda wish for is that it could be a bit simpler because all the parent needs to do is reset the child to Tab 1; it doesn't need full control over child tabs. But alas, it looks like it's all or nothing.